# How is the work done by a battery (when connected to a capacitor) independent of time?

Tags: electrostatics, capacitance, batteries

We know that W bybattery = V(It) = VQ, which is time-dependent. But when the battery is connected to a capacitor then W bybattery = 1/2 (CV^2), where C and V both are time-independent, hence W bybattery is coming to be time independent in this case. I am not able to understand why this happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This independence from time only arises when said circuit is in 'steady-state' which is essentially after infinite time. This steady-state refers to the time when the capacitor in the circuit is completely charged and current is no more flowing through it (assuming direct current and not alternating current).

Otherwise, the following equation stands true:

$Q$ = $Q_{o}(1-e^{-t/\tau})$

where $Q_{o}$ is the theoretical maximum possible charge on the capacitor and $\tau$ is the 'time-constant' of the R-C circuit, given by R times C, R being the resistance in the circuit and C being the capacitance of the capacitor. Clearly, this equation isn't time independent.

Answer (score 0):

It is not independent in the case of a capacitor, the value which you gave as work done by battery in case of a capacitor is the value in steady state which is after infinite time.
Whatever your circuit is you can calculate the value of charge as a function of time using KVL and integration and then the work done by battery at any given time is W=qV.